# Refresh UITableView using UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I insert `UIRefreshControl` in my tblView, when I pulldown my table view it's call method `cellForRowAtIndex` but my array list has no element then why it has been called? code for `UIRefreshControl` in `viewDidLoad` Method :

```
refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]init];
[self.tblView addSubview:refreshControl];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshTablee) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

code for refreshTablee is:

```
#pragma mark:refresh table
- (void)refreshTablee {
    //TODO: refresh your data
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
    page=1;
    slot = 10;
    HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:true];
    [apiObj getAskQuestion:@{@"user_id":usr.usrid,@"owner_id":usr.owner_id ,@"page":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",page]}];
    [backupArr removeAllObjects];
    [questionList removeAllObjects];
}
```

Table methods are:

```
#pragma mark:table view delegate datasource
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return questionList.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   //code for returning cell
    return cell;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if ((int)indexPath.row == (slot-2)) {
        page = page+1;
        slot = slot+10;

        HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:true];

       [apiObj getAskQuestion:@{@"user_id":usr.usrid,@"owner_id":usr.owner_id ,@"page":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",page]}];
    }
}
```

Comment: because you forgot to refresh the tableview in your refreshTablee methods.

Answer (score 1):

as per @dreamBegin suggestion I reload my table in refreshTablee method and its working. Thanks for reply@dreamBegin

```
#pragma mark:refresh table
- (void)refreshTablee {
    //TODO: refresh your data
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
    page=1;
    slot = 10;
    HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:true];
   [apiObj getAskQuestion:@{@"user_id":usr.usrid,@"owner_id":usr.owner_id ,@"page":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",page]}];
    [backupArr removeAllObjects];
    [questionList removeAllObjects];
    [self.tblView reloadData];
}
```